# Python get num occurrences of elements in each of several lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, collections

I have a 4 corpuses:

```
C1 = ['hello','good','good','desk']
C2 = ['nice','good','desk','paper']
C3 = ['red','blue','green']
C4 = ['good']
```

I want to define a list of words, and for each - get the occurances per corpus.
so if

> l= ['good','blue']

I will get

```
res_df =  word. C1. C2. C3. C4
          good.  2. 1.  0.   1
          blue.  0. 0.  1.   0
```

My corpus is very large so I am looking for efficient way.
What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what  did you try, how will you solve it for smaller sizes ? .. if you know the solution for smaller sizes, why doesn't it work for larger ones ?

Comment: I assume you already gave a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter ?

Comment: Pandas can handle this requirement fairly easily.  Are you using Pandas here?

Comment: @Sala To my undestranding, Counter get all the words and I want only a subset

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How can I do this with pandas?

Comment: @Cranjis If this is about Pandas, then why didn't you add that tag to the question?

Comment: shouldn't C4 have a 1 lined up with "good" in the res_df?

Comment: @ScottC 10x fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is filter values by list converted to set and then count by `Counter`, last pass to DataFrame with add `0` and integers:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'C1':C1, 'C2':C2, 'C3':C3, 'C4':C4}

s = set(l)     

df = (pd.DataFrame({k:Counter([y for y in v if y in s]) for k, v in d.items()})
        .fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
      C1  C2  C3  C4
good   2   1   0   1
blue   0   0   1   0
```

If possible not existing values in list:

```
from collections import Counter

l= ['good','blue','non']

d = {'C1':C1, 'C2':C2, 'C3':C3, 'C4':C4}

s = set(l)     

df = (pd.DataFrame({k:Counter([y for y in v if y in s]) for k, v in d.items()})
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .reindex(l, fill_value=0))
print (df)
    
      C1  C2  C3  C4
good   2   1   0   1
blue   0   0   1   0
non    0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use python lib Counter

```
counts = [[Counter(C)[word] for C in (C1, C2, C3, C4)] for word in l]
res_df = pd.DataFrame(counts, columns=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'], index=l)
```

output

```
      C1  C2  C3  C4
good   2   1   0   1
blue   0   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `.loc`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': Counter(C1), 'C2': Counter(C2), 'C3': Counter(C3), 'C4': Counter(C4)}).loc[l].fillna(0).astype('int')
```

Example below:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

C1 = ['hello','good','good','desk']
C2 = ['nice','good','desk','paper']
C3 = ['red','blue','green']
C4 = ['good']

l= ['good','blue']

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': Counter(C1), 'C2': Counter(C2), 'C3': Counter(C3), 'C4': Counter(C4)}).loc[l].fillna(0).astype('int')

print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
      C1  C2  C3  C4
good   2   1   0   1
blue   0   0   1   0
```